# How to remove duplicated white spaces in a string and count the number of removed spaces in Java?

Tags: java, counting

This forum has a solution for removing duplicated white spaces in java using

```
String.replaceAll()
```

However this solution can't be applied if we need to count the removed white spaces. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: you will have to implement your own function, this does not exist by default.

Answer (score 1):

Before you `replaceAll()` you could iterate over all characters with `stringVar.toCharArray()` and count.

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

```
 String s = "     ";
 String whiteSpaceLess = s.replaceAll("  ", "");
 int diff = s.length() - whiteSpaceLess.length();
```

Comment: This would replace all White spaces. And replaceAll takes two arguments

Comment: @Templar yes you are right, I hit some site errors, so I did submit the answer prematurely and couldn't edit.

Answer (score 1):

Simply retain the original string in another variable. After trimming it from extra spaces, just calculate the length difference: this is the number of spaces removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a String s,

```
String t = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
System.out.println(t);
int count = s.length() - t.length();
System.out.println(count);
```

You can remove the whitespaces using replaceAll, and count the difference in length between the strings to get the number of removed spaces.